# How to print more than one line above in Python?

Tags: python, printing

I understand this is possible,

```
for r in range(0,1000):
    print(("l1" + str(r)), end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

where this would print on the same line. Is it possible to do something like "\r\r" which will print one line above as well?

Comment: replace `\r` with `\n`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri that just goes down... not above

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to `print` anything on the line above in Python. Since newlines are simply \n, a string like:

```
Hello 
World
```

Ends up looking like:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Multiple `print` statements only add to this stream of characters, which makes it impossible to add anything before what has already been written, or in your case, the line above.

Comment: thanks you, also it is possible to add what has already been written, but yeah i guess you can't do two lines up.